# Newbie in JSF: composition vs composite

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I am starting development on a new web application which uses JSF 2 as the view technology.
I have no prior experience with JSF and am a bit confused about the concepts.
I read some documentation on JSF and the main idea was that it a component based framework. Applications are built from components.

But now there are two ways of creating a component, as I understood:
1. **composition** - a collection of components which can be included in a page
2. **composite** - a new component that encapsulate some components and exposes an interface to users

**What is the basic rule in choosing between them?**
For example, I want to show a list of products to an user. For this list I should create my own component which I add to the main layout, to separate the view code. So should this list be a composition or composite?

I hope somebody can help me clear up this basic stuff.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for [**composition** (templating)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) when you want a reuseable template which you normally include only *once* in the main view. E.g. header, menu, footer, single table, etc. Go for [**composite component**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) when you want a reuseable component with a bean-value-binding which you can include as many as you want in the main view. E.g. a group of label, input and message components (although a tag file is often better for this).

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/)

Comment: Do you have a reference to some documentation that supports your comment here?Seeing as composition was really the only re-use option in jsf 1.x and composite has only been introduced in 2.x, why would the behavior of composition change?  We were using (probably abusing) composition extensively in a project, then tried to run in 2.0 and found everything using composition was quite broken.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following link to the JEE 6 Tutorial would help.

[Determining Whether You Need a Custom Component or Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavh.html)